# Syntax Error in query expression with vb 6.0

Tags: vb6

```
sql = "update Attendance set Attended=Attended+1 where Student ID like 15001"
db.Execute (sql)
```

is is showing :

> "syntax error(missing operator) in query expression 'Student ID like
>   15001'

Comment: Enclose field name `Student ID` in appropriate symbols (`[Student ID]` for Microsoft SQL).

Answer (score 0):

If realy you have a space between Student and ID tehn your query must be :

```
sql = "update Attendance set Attended=Attended+1 where [Student ID] like 15001"
db.Execute (sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

sql should always be written with an _. For Example Student ID should always be Student_ID so that it has the idea of reading which column it needs to filter its search. For future purposes always create a column name with an _.

```
sql = "update Attendance set Attended=Attended+1 where Student_ID like 15001"
db.Execute (sql)
```

or

```
sql = "update Attendance set Attended=Attended+1 where [Student ID] like 15001"
db.Execute (sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something that looks a bit cleaner...

```
sql = "Update tblAttendance SET "
sql = sql & " Attended = Attended + 1 "
sql = sql & " Where Student_ID = 15001 "
db.execute SQL <-- no paranthesis
```